# QT Creator Run Error on Mac OSX 10.6.8

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I created a widget project in QT Creator 5.1.1. I didn't change anything. When I try to run, it says this:

not using the clang compiler for C++ inputs
assembler command failed with exit code 1(use -v o see invocation)
[main.o] Error 1

Here is the compile output:

20:59:07: Running steps for project Cloud_Browser...
20:59:07: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
20:59:08: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
/Users/admin/Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/bin/uic ../Cloud_Browser/mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
/usr/bin/clang++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Wall -W -fPIE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../../Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -I../Cloud_Browser -I../../Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/include -I../../Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/include/QtWidgets -I../../Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I../../Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/include/QtGui -I../../Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I../../Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/include/QtCore -I../../Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I. -I/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -I. -F/Users/admin/Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/lib -o main.o ../Cloud_Browser/main.cpp
clang: warning: not using the clang compiler for C++ inputs
/var/folders/RY/RY5t5feQGr03EMboTvgxTk+++TI/-Tmp-/cc-6mOSQM.s:40:suffix or operands invalid for `push'
/var/folders/RY/RY5t5feQGr03EMboTvgxTk+++TI/-Tmp-/cc-6mOSQM.s:71:suffix or operands invalid for`push'
/var/folders/RY/RY5t5feQGr03EMboTvgxTk+++TI/-Tmp-/cc-6mOSQM.s:75:suffix or operands invalid for `push'
/var/folders/RY/RY5t5feQGr03EMboTvgxTk+++TI/-Tmp-/cc-6mOSQM.s:183:suffix or operands invalid for`pop'
/var/folders/RY/RY5t5feQGr03EMboTvgxTk+++TI/-Tmp-/cc-6mOSQM.s:192:suffix or operands invalid for `push'
/var/folders/RY/RY5t5feQGr03EMboTvgxTk+++TI/-Tmp-/cc-6mOSQM.s:196:suffix or operands invalid for`push'
/var/folders/RY/RY5t5feQGr03EMboTvgxTk+++TI/-Tmp-/cc-6mOSQM.s:270:suffix or operands invalid for `pop'
/var/folders/RY/RY5t5feQGr03EMboTvgxTk+++TI/-Tmp-/cc-6mOSQM.s:114983:unknown section type: non_lazy_symbol_pointers
/var/folders/RY/RY5t5feQGr03EMboTvgxTk+++TI/-Tmp-/cc-6mOSQM.s:114983:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 76 (L).
/var/folders/RY/RY5t5feQGr03EMboTvgxTk+++TI/-Tmp-/cc-6mOSQM.s:114984:Unknown pseudo-op: .indirect_symbol
/var/folders/RY/RY5t5feQGr03EMboTvgxTk+++TI/-Tmp-/cc-6mOSQM.s:114984:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 95 (_).
clang: error: assembler command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
20:59:11: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Cloud_Browser (kit: Desktop Qt 5.1.1 clang 64bit)
When executing step 'Make'
20:59:11: Elapsed time: 00:03.

Please help. I just want to run the project.